# Showing a new div when an input is filled in without clicking out of the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to check to see if an input is filled in as you are typing in it? Right now my code checks to see if the input is filled in and then displays a div after the user clicks out of the input. I am wanting the div to display once the future validation methods have been met...without having to click outside of the input.

Also is there a way to keep the div to display if the user would have to go back and delete the data in an input?

```js
$(function () {   
    var _=$('input');
    
    _.change(function() {
        
        if (_.filter(function (){return $(this).val().length }).length==_.length)
        $('.next').show();
        else
            $('.next').hide();
            
    });
});
```

```css
.next { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text" />
<input id="email" type="text" />


<a class="next">show div</a>
```

Comment: Uh, rather unsual to use an underscore as variable name, because it could get confused with [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)…

Comment: This was a previous answer on stackoverflow that I found that best suited my needs. Just haven't changed it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onchange` event is only fired if you leave (blur) the input element. To track updates independent of the input focus state, you have to use another event type, for example `onkeydown` or `onkeypress`.

```
$(function () {   
    var $input = $('input');

    $input.on('keypress', function() {
        if ($input.filter(function (){return $(this).val().length }).length == $input.length) {
            $('.next').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.next').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting the div to display this way? Unless I missed something? https://jsfiddle.net/02gLhbpm/

Comment: @Becky Because the `if` condition is always `false`: `$input.filter(…).length` is always `1` (only one element is returned by the `filter` call) and `$input.length` returns the number of inputs, which is always `2` in this example. So the condition reads `if(1 == 2)` which is never `true` and thus only the `else` branch is ever executed. It is hard to tell, what exactly you are trying to do. ----------- Maybe you should start explaining what are you trying to do, not how are you trying it to do…

Comment: Thanks! The div show if an input field is deleted, but when you start typing into it again, the div goes away? How could I go about keeping the div there even if something has to be retyped again?

Answer (score 0):

Using keyup as your event listener should make this achievable. Something along the lines of:

```
var _ = $('input');

_.keyUp(function(){
if (your validation rules are satisfied){
//Shows next button if validation rules are satisfied
$(this).siblings(".next").toggle();
}
else{
//Hides next button if validation rules are satisfied
$(this).siblings(".next").toggle();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @feeela, the "change" event only fires once focus is lost. The following code is simple and will meet your requirements, including keeping the `DIV` visible even if the inputs become blank, again.

Try this instead:

```js
$(function () {   
  $('input').on('keypress', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) { // Gets the firing input's value
      $('.next').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can set variables, but this code is so simple, there's no real need for it:

```js
$(function () {   
  var $inputs = $('input');
  var $next = $('.next');
  $inputs.on('keypress', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) { // We still want to use "this" here, so we're only examining the input that fired the event; otherwise, it will only get the value of the first input in the set
      $next.show();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I think the requirement is not that one of the boxes meet the requirement.

So in my example, if any key is pressed in any input, all of them are then checked. As soon as you meet the requirements the Div gets shown.

It uses the keyup event and each feature of jquery. You can fill the input at random. I had keydown first, but basically you would then be checking too soon.

```js
// JavaScript source code
$(function () {
var _ = $('input');

_.keyup(function () {
    var allOk = true;
    _.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            allOk = false;
        }
    });
    if (allOk) {
        $('.next').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.next').hide();
    }
});
});
```

```css
.next { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text" />
<input id="email" type="text" />


<a class="next">show div</a>
```